# Use cases for new Django 1.4 project structure?

Tags: django, project-structure

I guess this is sort of a followup question to [Where should i create django apps in django 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888388/where-should-i-create-django-apps-in-django-1-4)  The final answer there seemed to be "nobody knows why Django changed the project structure" -- which seems a bit unsatisfactory.

We are starting up a new Django project, and currently we are following the basic structure outlined at http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html:

```
├── project
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── app1
│   │   └── app2
│   ├── libs
│   │   ├── lib1
│   │   └── lib2
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

But I think we also are anticipating a multi-developer environment comprising largely independent applications with common project-level components, so it seems cleaner to me to separate out the project and app paths.

```
├── project
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   └── app2
├── libs
│   ├── lib1
│   └── lib2
└── manage.py
```

It's hard to come up with any specific, non-stylistic rationale for this, though.  (I've mostly worked only with single-app projects before now, so I may be missing something here.)

Mainly, I'm motivated by the fact that Django 1.4 seems to be moving in the latter direction.  I assume there is *some* rationale or expected use case that motivated this change, but I've only seen speculation on what it might be.

Questions:

1. What was the motivation for the 1.4 project structure change?
2. Are there use cases where having apps inside/outside of the project makes a non-trivial impact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's much easier to extract an app from a project because there are no more imports like this:

   ```
   from projectname.appname.models import MyModel
   ```

   instead you import them the same way you would import apps which are installed via a python package
2. if you use i18n then this could make an impact because makemessages searches for translation strings in the current directory. a good way to translate apps and the project using a single .po file is to create the locale folder outside the project dir

   ```
   ├── project
   │   ├── settings.py
   │   ├── urls.py
   │   └── wsgi.py
   ├── app1
   ├── app2
   ├── locale
   │   ├── en
   │   └── de
   └── manage.py
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I marked the earlier response as an answer, but I ran into this blog post off the IRC archives that seems to have some additional info.

http://blog.tinbrain.net/blog/2012/mar/15/django-vs-pythonpath/

As I understand it, the gist is:

- When you're developing, `manage.py` *implicitly* sets up `PYTHONPATH` to see the project-level code, with the result that `import myapp` works for an app defined inside the project.
- When you deploy, you generally don't run `manage.py`, so you would have to say `import myproject.myapp`, thus things break on deployment if you don't know about this.
- The "standard" fix is to add the project to `PYTHONPATH`, but this results in double-imports (`myapp` and `myproject.myapp`), which can generate weird behavior on things like signals.

So the 1.4 project structure seems mainly intended to eliminate the possibility of devs relying on an odd effect of `manage.py`.