# In django1.4, where to create the app is better

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should i create django apps in django 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888388/where-should-i-create-django-apps-in-django-1-4)

In Django version `1.4`, the structure has changed, the `manage.py` get out to the top level.
Use the tutorial in the django webiste, the project's name is mysite, the structure is like this:

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

and I want to create a app. In the tutorial, It place the app right next to the manage.py, so the app is on the top level too, just like this:

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

so:

1. what is the different if  I create the app in the secend level(as right next to the settings.py) ?
2. if I create the app on the top level, and there is some static file, the `mysite` and the `polls` all should to use, so where to place the `static/` directory ?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure/11222631#11222631

Comment: @Hedde yes, but I want the static file to be used for both the project `mysite` and the app `poll`, in the situation, is it good to place the app in the second level?

Comment: you want a static file to be used both in the app and project? are you talking about template presentation? how has that to do with project layout?

Comment: django 1.4 mades apps more plugable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django changed the project layout to end the dreaded era of `myproject.myapp.something` imports. When you have those type of imports scattered around your codebase, you can't move anything around or re-use the app(s) in another project. The new layout (apps at the same level as project), makes the imports app-relative, rather than project-relative, simplifying things greatly.

The only thing that should go in the root directoy of your code is your app directories, your project directory and manage.py. Anything project-wide (settings, templates, static files, etc, should go in the project directory.

That said, `STATIC_ROOT` should point to `myproject/static`, but you should not manually create that directory, nor manually put anything in it. Static files tied to a particular app, should go in that app's `static` directory. Any project-wide static files should go in an entirely different directory (not the same as either `STATIC_ROOT` or `MEDIA_ROOT`). You then add that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, so Django will include it in development and when running the `collectstatic` management command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template to start the project, like this:

```
https://github.com/goinnn/django-base-template
```

In these templates the place of the applications is defined already